# Change text with javascript

Tags: javascript

My website is based on a platform and I can change a little bit of the layout, but certain parts render code automatically. My problem? It is in English and I need it in Spanish. I can add javascript before the body of the website but I can't change the html directly so I was thinking I could use onload to change the text. What do you guys think? I can use jQuery, too, if that helps.

I need to change this:

```
 <div class="c_wrapper">
     <h3 class="d_customize_title" align="left">
         <span id="left_title">
            Playera Max
        </span>
         <a onclick="d.showProductInfo(); return false;" href="#">
            Product details
        </a>
    </h3>
 </div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="c_wrapper">
    <h3 class="d_customize_title" align="left">
        <span id="left_title">
            Playera Max
        </span>
        <a onclick="d.showProductInfo(); return false;" href="#">
            Detalles del producto
        </a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Altering the text via JavaScript is a measure of absolute last resort as it means users with JavaScript disabled and search engines will see different content to the majority of your users.

Comment: Might help to tell us what platform you are using.  For many of these, there is a "right" way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Find the part in the theme (platform) that is rendering the code and change it from there (best option)
2. Use jQuery to replace the `html`:

---

```
$(".c_wrapper a").text("Detalles del producto");
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".c_wrapper a").text("Detalles del producto");
</script>

</body>
```

**Working Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/vtHBV/

Comment: I'm so new a this , where do i place that code? within <script></script> before </head>?

Comment: @JoseRuacho You would place that code within <script> tags somewhere within the <body> tags would work fine.

Comment: @JoseRuacho Mira mi ultima edicion

Comment: Worked like a charm! You have no idea how much i've been trying to do this , thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned it's a bit hacky to do this with Javascript but here's another way to do it without jQuery:

```
// helper to make sure we get a sibling that is an element
function getNextSibling(node){
    sibling = node.nextSibling;
    while (sibling.nodeType != 1){
        sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
    }
    return sibling;
}

// set text
getNextSibling(document.getElementById('left_title')).innerHTML = 'Detalles del producto';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/dkymR/

Answer (score 0):

This is perfect for jQuery, if you don't have control over the content when you initially load it it may be the best option. Below is a working sample for your example:

```
$(function(){
      $("#left_title + a").text("Detalles del producto");
});
```